# How should I make log4j logging in Java work with JPype?

Tags: java, log4j2, jpype

I have some Java code that uses log4j logging. As a standalone application it works fine and log statements are generated as expected. Now, I am invoking this Java code through JPype service calls. The jar files are being added to the JVM as follows. Surprisingly, the Java code still works fine and I can see the output but no log files are created.

```
   def start_jvm():
      javapath = JavaAlgorithmAttributes.java_resolver_path
      cp = "-Djava.class.path=%s" % (                
            + f"{javapath}/vendor/log4j-core-2.17.1.jar;"
            + f"{javapath}/vendor/log4j-api-2.17.1.jar;"
            + f"{javapath}/vendor/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.17.1.jar;"
            + f"{javapath}/vendor/slf4j-api.jar;"
            + f"{javapath}/properties/log4j2.xml"

    )
        
     startJVM(getDefaultJVMPath(), "-ea", cp)
```

Could someone please provide some insights?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, got it. Turns out, the log4j2.xml files needs to be passed to the jvm as an argument, not the way I was doing above. It should be added as follows:

```
    -Dlog4j.configurationFile=log4j2.xml
```

*Regards*